How large must the sample size be to guarantee that the length of the confidence interval is less than or equal to δ > 0?
I don't understand confidence intervals generally. In our lecture we had this:

Given $X_i$ be Bernoulli distributed to the parameter $p$ and independent under $\mathbb P_p$. Here we have $p \in \Theta = [0,1]$. Set $H_n = X_1+...+X_n$ and $q_n=\frac{H_n} n$.
The following is a confidence interval to confidence level $1-\alpha$:
$$I = (\frac{q+\frac{c^2}{2n} \pm \frac c {\sqrt n} \sqrt{q(1-q)+\frac{c^2}{4n}}}{1+\frac{c^2}{n}})$$
where $c\geq \Phi^{-1}(1-\frac \alpha 2)$

What that means, according to the lecture, is this:
$\mathbb P_p(p \in I) \geq 1-\alpha$ for all $p$. (1)
Q1: In (1) it has $p$ in the index of $\mathbb P$. So we use the probability measure belonging to $p$ to calculate the probability of a term depending on $p$? That seems non sense to me...?
The task is the following: "How large must the sample size be to guarantee that the length of the confidence interval is less than or equal to $δ > 0$?"
Q2: How can I calculate the length of the interval if there is a random variable, namely $q$ in it? I would just substract the first interval bound from the second bound, but that will only work for numbers. Here I will have a random variable in my result...

$\mathbb P_p(p \in I)$ is really saying "the probability that the confidence interval covers $p$ assuming that the parameter is in fact $p$" and is not something to worry about.

You would expect the location of the end points of a confidence interval to vary with the observations.  It is not unreasonable for the width of the interval to vary too: this also happens when you find a confidence interval for the mean of a normal distribution with unknown mean and variance.  In your expression,  the width is maximised when $q=\frac12$ and minimised when $q=0$ or $1$, so you can put bounds on the width if you wish.
